# last problem when scraping bet365.com with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

After looking for information in the community,  I have seen in a post that the next code worked until some days ago:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                                  "source": """
                                    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                                      get: () => undefined
                                    })
                                  """
                                })
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
                                    {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'})
browser.get('https://www.bet365.com')
```

After that, the next worked as a solution:
Open the file chromedriver.exe with Notepad ++ and searched and replaced "cdc_" with "xyz_" and saved the file. And add this line to the options of the chromedriver: options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

I don't know why this don't work for me. I am using Chrome 88.0.4324.146 and the chromedriver version 88.0.4324.96, and executing this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
browser=webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
                                  "source": """
                                    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
                                      get: () => undefined
                                    })
                                  """
                                })
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', 
                                    {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'})
browser.get('https://www.bet365.com')
```

But after executing the page gets stuck loading until it crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import subprocess
#other imports

subprocess.Popen(
   '"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222', shell=True)
   
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.bet365.com')
```

### It seems that the site detects the automation some how , work around is to open chrome using debug address and then connect selenium to this using above code . Change the chrome.exe according to your environment

**Note: Make sure you close all the chrome browsers before running this script**

Comment: I think I got you, but I have some questions. What do you mean by open chrome using debug address, could you explain how to do it? And I suppose you mean, once you open chrome 'using debug address', ensure that the only chrome tab opened is that one before running the code above, isn't it?

Comment: @scraper just run the code as it is , close all chrome and run the code this will start chrome with port 9222 opened for debuggin purpose. We can connect to this address from selenium chromedriver 
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222")

Comment: I wonder how many times bet365 will change their code for how many bots they get.

Comment: @PDHide is there any chance to do the same but in incognito mode(private browsing)? Cause as you are creating a proccess with chrome, the option: `# options.add_argument("--incognito")` doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @scraper just use subprocess.Popen(
   '"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222' --incognito, shell=True)

Comment: How would you close the chrome window afterwards? I mean `driver.quit()` ends the connection to the chromw window from Python, but it does not close the actual window. And by the way, is it possible to run all this in headless mode?

Comment: Just add more arguments , to the popen --headless

Comment: Search for commandline arguments for chrome , ask as a separate question if still in doubt please

Comment: Please upvote the answer also if it was helpful