# Getting blocked by a website with selenium and chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm having some trouble trying to access a web site (bet365.com) with a chrome driver and selenium (I'm quite being "blocked").

I can access the site with my ordinary chrome but when I try with chrome driver, it doesn't work.

I had this problem before and corrected it by using some options as below (python):

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'PATH_TO\chromedriver.exe')
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
  "source": """
    Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
      get: () => undefined
    })
  """
})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.enable", {})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36'})

driver.get("https://www.bet365.com/")
```

Now, the problem came back and this code is not working anymore to bypass the protection.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe you're not supposed to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [last problem when scraping bet365.com with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089231/last-problem-when-scraping-bet365-com-with-selenium)

Comment: Hello @Ricardo Guerra and undetected Selenium, your code actually worked for both bet365 and the site I was having trouble with. Thank you so much guys! 

Answer (score 10):

In case the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context* is getting detected a potential solution would be to use the [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) to initialize the *Chrome Browsing Context*.

[undetected-chromedriver](https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver) is an optimized Selenium Chromedriver patch which does not trigger anti-bot services like Distill Network / Imperva / DataDome / Botprotect.io. It automatically downloads the driver binary and patches it.

- Code Block:

  ```
  import undetected_chromedriver as uc
  from selenium import webdriver

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
  driver.get('https://bet365.com')
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Undetected Chromedriver not loading correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529808/undetected-chromedriver-not-loading-correctly/65534593#65534593)

Comment: It works, in the aspect that it avoids the Out of Memory error, but it is not possible to interact with the page.I mean, if you programmatically click on "In-Play", the page doesn't load. If you just open Bet365 with the In-Play link, it also doesn't work.

Comment: @puppet, did you find any solution?

Comment: No, nothing so far

Comment: Could this be an issue where a website is protected by recaptcha