# Python selenium gets stuck on site loading screen

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

First of all, this is the [website](https://www.gamermarkt.com/) I use.

**The code block I used:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
browserProfile = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browserProfile.add_argument("start-maximized")
browserProfile.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
browserProfile.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36')
browserProfile.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
browserProfile.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
browser = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=browserProfile)
browser.get('https://www.gamermarkt.com')
```

**ChromeDriver image:**

[image]

stays on this screen.

I think there is a bot block on the site, but I have no idea how to bypass it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you explore the following code:

```
import time
time.sleep(1) #sleep for 1 sec
time.sleep(0.25) #sleep for 250 milliseconds
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with sleep, no matter how long I wait, it still stays on this screen. I think there is a bot block on the site, but I have no idea how to bypass it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092682/getting-blocked-by-a-website-with-selenium-and-chromedriver

Comment: Another potential solution: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/the-art-of-not-getting-blocked-how-i-used-selenium-python-to-scrape-facebook-and-tiktok-fd6b31dbe85f

Comment: Solved with undetected_chromedriver thanks

Comment: When I run undetected_chromedriver with headless, the same problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your chromedriver is up-to-date.
In your browser goto help -> about Google Chrome
and check your version and then get the latest chromedriver
from chromedriver download