# Https ERROR 403 , Https ERROR 403 , Https ERROR 403

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web, web-crawler

I was making web-crawler crawling images from pixabay.
At first, https 403 forbidden error occurred.
so I added user agent in my code.
but the same problem continued

this is my code to test error

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request

current_path=os.getcwd()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(current_path+r'\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
url=r'https://pixabay.com/ko/photos/search'

season=['spring', 'summer', 'autumm', 'winter']
new_url=url+'/'+season[0]+'%20풍경'
driver.get(new_url)

#useragent
header = {"my user agent"} 
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=header)
img_url=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'photo-result-image').get_attribute('src')
workingdir_test='.\dataset\dataset_test'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, workingdir_test+season[0]+'.jpg')
```

Comment: I don't even understand what you are trying to do... what is it your think that using a urllib.request.Request with a custom user agent does for the selenium webdriver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting blocked by a website with selenium and chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66092682/getting-blocked-by-a-website-with-selenium-and-chromedriver)