# WebDriverWait runs longer than intended

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to wait for an element to be clickable and then click it, but WebDriverWait does not seem to work as intended. The timeout option does not seem to work either - the program runs much longer than 5 seconds and eventually throws me a "TimeoutException: TimedPromise timed out after 300000 ms". I did not set any implicit waits, and even tried setting it to 0 before I run the code, but that changed nothing. Any ideas what the problem could be?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

binary = FirefoxBinary(r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

browser.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/login/")

submit = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout=5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]')))
submit.click()
```

Comment: Xpath for `Reject All` button is `//*[@id="onetrust-reject-all-handler"]`. Missing a `-` in `...all-handler`

Comment: Refer this link - [Link](https://automationpanda.com/2019/01/15/web-element-locators-for-test-automation/). The locators must be `1/1` match. And `TimeoutException` means the element was not found.  `//*[@id="onetrust-reject-allhandler"]` does not locate any element in the DOM.

Comment: @pmadhu Sorry, I had the correct xpath but lost the missing `-` when copying the code. I have the same issue with the correct xpath.

Comment: @pmadhu but why is my timeout exception not 5s like specified but much longer?

Comment: I am using Chrome Browser - `chromedriver.exe` and it works fine. May be its because of the browser settings. Not sure

Comment: Check this once - https://stackoverflow.com/q/67473065/16452840

Comment: @pmadhu thanks for your suggestions, It worked for after setting it up using chromedriver. I think there was a problem with my firefox driver being outdated or not properly set up, not exactly sure. Was using it for a long time without any updates to the driver (the browser is updated), don't exactly know yet and will look into it. Thanks!